# in vb.net and asp.net how to get meta tag information of any web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm implementing one web which requires the content of meta tag. How do I get the content?

Comment: you want to read some page and parse it for meta tags?

Comment: Are you talking about a meta tag on your web page or another web page? Can you try to explain a bit more?

Comment: hi MikeEast on any web page i just give url of page and i want meta tag information of that web page

Comment: Hi Robert yah i wanna parse meta tag info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and use the free Html Agility Pack

- [Download](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- [Some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)
- [Convert C# to VB.Net](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)